# Android SDK manager repository.xml verification error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I am using a windows7 32-bit OS. Whenever I try to start Android SDK manager I get the below error.

XML verification failed for http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml.
Line -१:-१, Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

This error is been troubling me for weeks now. Can anyone help?

Comment: what type of java do you have in your computer

Comment: I am using Java SE Development Kit 8u40 downloaded from [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: have you tried updating your adt?